# Anconda R version - How to upgrade to 4.0 and later

Tags: graphs, gaussian, rstudio, anaconda

I use R through the anaconda navigator, which manages all my package installations. I need to use [qgraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qgraph/index.html) for a project, which is dependent on [mnormt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mnormt/index.html) library, which in turn needs RStudio verion >4.0

I think the solution to my problem would be to upgrade Anaconda R to the latest R version, but the r-base search in conda has no R version greater than 3.6. Any help in upgrading Anaconda R to newer versions would be very useful.

The problem is in installing qgraph, which stops with errors in installing dependencies (pysch)

During startup - Warning messages:

```
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'mnormt', details:
  call: library.dynam("mnormt", pkg, library)
  error: shared object 'mnormt.dylib' not found
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'psych'
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to create a new environment and then you can install R 4.+ in Anaconda. Follow these steps.

```
conda create --name r4-base
```

[image]

After activating `r4-base` run these commands

```
conda activate r4-base
conda install -c conda-forge r-base
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 r-base
```

Finally, you will notice `r-basa` version 4 will be installed.

[image]

Thereafter, you can install any supported packages. But with this only, you won't have the ability to use it in the Jupyter notebook. You need to install `install.packages('IRkernel')` and Jupyter notebook as well if you want to use it. Otherwise you are good to go with R-Studio.

For Jupyter Installation and RKernel.

```
conda install jupyter
```

Then open the R console. Write in R console

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Congrats! You can use Notebook for Python and R.

Comment: To add to this, sometimes the default version of `r-base` is not what you want.  You can specify version with `conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

Rstudio does not support Anaconda so you are stuck with the version they provide. Your best option is to install R and RStudio outside Anaconda.

Comment: I have found that (at least in the last year or so) I can run Rstudio with r installed through anaconda. I just have to activate the environment with the r version that I want and then launch rstudio from that environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try install through anaconda prompt and the following path

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-mnormt
```

Then install qgraph one more time

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it fails with the same error. It looks like r-base doesn't install an R version beyond 3.5.  I finally had to install R 4.0 outside anaconda and use it, which is a shame. I like managing libraries through conda.

Comment: Yes, Anaconda is quite user-unfriendly to R. Maybe you can use R-studio instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps seemed to resolve the issue for me on my mac.

1. Create an environment using Anaconda. Give it a name, say "Environment Name".
2. Launch that environment using terminal. "Environment Name" > "Open Terminal"
3. Inside terminal type  the following command.

   > brew install r

Answer (score 0):

The code above didn't work for me.  I use macOS.  Instead I used the following code and it worked.  You need to fill in a name of your environment for "your_name_here" and choose version numbers for python and R:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge    
conda config --set channel_priority strict    
conda search r-base  
conda create -n your_name_here python=3.X   
conda activate your_name_here  
conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.X.X    
conda install jupyter
```

Now, install RStudio in your environment via Anaconda. In RStudio, write in the R console:

```
install.packages('IRkernel')   
IRkernel::installspec()
```